# Linq - Create a set-length list with default values where empty

Tags: c#, linq, list, merge

I know this should be easy to do, but suppose, in my C# application, I have a `IEnumerable<string>` and I need to create a larger enumerable with `null`s for the extra values.

So, simply for example's sake, suppose my enumerable has 12 elements and I need to create a final list of 24 elements (therefore the final 12 being nulls). I know I could program it using a for loop, but there has to be an easy way to do this using Linq and I'm just not sure which method to use.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using Enumerable.Range or Repeat

```
var list = yourList.Concat(Enumerable.Range(1, 24).Select(i => null)).Take(24);

var list = yourList.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(null, 24)).Take(24);
```

Comment: Thanks so much!! - I **REALLY** like the `take(24)` idea!

Comment: @JohnBustos This is the safest as you don't run into exceptions if the original sequence has more than 24 items (also doesn't potentially iterate your original sequence twice).  Only possible caveat is if it does have more than 24 this will truncate it, but that seems fairly reasonable.

Comment: I can see that... Truly the safest way. Thank you!

Comment: note that var list is actually an IEnumerable you need to call ToList to get an actual list out of it

Answer (score 2):

[Repeat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348899(v=vs.100).aspx).

```
List<string> list = new List<string>() { "one", "two", "three" };
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat((string)null, 10));
```

You can do this to get 24 elements.

```
list.AddRange(Enumerable.Repeat((string)null, 24-list.Count()));
```

Comment: `Addrange` and `Repeat` - Simple and makes perfect sense too!! - Thank you so much, @Nikki!

Answer (score 2):

Here's the first thing that popped into my head:

```
currentList = currentList.Concat(                 // build onto your current list
    Enumerable.Range(1, 24 - currentList.Count()) // number of elements needed
    .Select(i => (string)null));                  // what you want the element to be
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, @Cory, it's taking me a bit to wrap my head around, but it seems like the way you've broken it down, it would make a good pattern to know how to do it for any situation. thanks!!!